# Is there a keyboard shortcut to toggle/show Inspector in React Native?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

While building the UI of an app in React Native, I tend to use Toggle/Show inspector a lot. To Toggle/Show inspector, I hit `CMD + D` on iOS and `CMD + M` on Android to open the menu and then I click on Toggle or Show Inspector.

Is there a keyboard shortcut for toggling the Inspector without opening the menu? For example, `CMD + R` reloads the app. I don't have to access the menu to do so.

If there are no shortcuts for the inspector, how can I assign a shortcut like `CMD + R`? Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: oh thanks cmd+d on my ios simulator brought up the menu to close the inspector, i had no idea how i opened it and it took me a lot of googling cause i had no idea what i did in the first place

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Cmd + i will bring up the Inspector (well, Debug) panel. Don't forget you can deactivate inspection mode by pressing the inspector button but still keep the panel on screen, which can be convenient when navigating around.

Comment: @rash.tay Feel free to accept my answer. Any time you like ;)

Comment: Thanks so much @sinewave440hz. Small yet so stinkin' good! :D

Comment: Is there a list of RN shortcuts somewhere?

Answer (score 19):

Yes, on iOS - 
`CMD + Ctrl + Z` -> `Show Inspector`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I can do the same by hitting `cmd + d -> Show Inspector`. But, I do not want to open the menu. I'd like to open the inspector directly rather than opening the menu and then pressing Show Inspector.

Comment: U r asking too much 

Comment: I don't think you are asking too much :) It would be really useful!